# How do phototransistor and photodiode work in multisim ? How can one cause the photodiode to trigger the phototransistor?

Tags: photodiode, phototransistor, multisim, photosensor

[image]

I would like to design this circuit shown in the picture. I have simulated it in Multisim. It functions as follows: When the switch is open, the phototransistor is high impedance, when the switch is closed it is low impedance. I wonder how to input this into Multisim. I would like to adjust current on phototransistor according to distance between photodiode and phototransistor. For example: if the distance is 1 metre, current on phototransistor is 10 mA; if distance is 2 m current on phototransistor is 4 mA. I have not found out how to do this in Multisim. Do you know how to do it in Multisim or do you know other software where this is possible?

Comment: "Do you suggest any software to simulate or Does Multisim any function to do" No software, except for some extremely specialized software with in-depth configuration, will be able to simulate dust, dispersion, mechanical noise in the direction of the light emitter and phototransistor, and so on. If you want to "simulate" this to a high level of fidelity, first do preliminary calculations using the datasheets of the devices, select device models, and construct a physical prototype to test with.

Comment: I edited your question rather heavily, could you look at the edit and check if I got it right semantically?

Comment: @caconyrn thanks for your edition. I think you have information about this issue. Can you help me please ?

Comment: When you say "photodiode" do you mean LED? The model of the phototransistor probably doesn't have the effect of the photocurrent, but you might be able to get some insight into the circuit with a current source into the base of the phototransistor (and just ignore the LED)

Comment: No, I obviously do not know how to do this or I would have written an answer. By the way, it is considered redundant to specifically ask for help/attention, people will gladly help without that.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a photodiode to trigger a phototransistor.

A photodiode is another kind of light detector, with a similar function to a phototransistor. It cannot be used to generate light (without damaging it). A diode that emits light is rather unimaginatively called a *light-emitting diode* or *LED*.

Comment: No. You can use photodioede to trigger a phototransistor. Can you look this datasheet please. http://optekinc.com/datasheets/OPB100EZ.pdf

Comment: The datasheet talks about an LED and a phototransistor. The word *photodiode* doesn't appear anywhere in it.

Comment: Anyway I couldn't use LED to trigger a phototransistor in Multisim. You can be right. I think I must set circuit on breadboard. Then I must test according to distance of between two component. Because it is not possible set in multisim to analyzing. By the way thank you so much for coorperation.

Comment: @user114800, you can model the phototransistor or photodiode as a CCCS, possibly with a parallel capacitance. The LED is just a diode as far as the electrical circuit is concerned, but the parameters are pretty far off from a silicon diode, so it takes some knowledge to tune up an LED model to give realistic results.

Answer (score 0):

You can't vary the distance between the photo diode and the photo transistor but you can vary the current through the diode, and thus control the current passing through the transistor. So instead of using a switch to switch the diode on and off, use a variable resistor to control the current through the PhotoDiode as I've done here.

[image: Photo Diode with 13mA current = transistor 13mA]

[image: Photo diode with 39mA current = transistor 39mA]